# TDWM filter voilation: Bad Unconstrained product Join

Tags: sql-update, teradata

I am working on an update statement where i have to update the incorrect ids with the correct one.
Below is my code:
Taking the correct and incorrect code in a volatile table:

```
    CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT
AS
(
SELECT 
   NAME
   ,DESC
   ,FIRST_VALUE(CODE) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,DESC,SRC_TYPE_CD 
          ORDER BY CODE) AS CORRECT_CODE
   ,CODE AS INCORRECT_CODE
   ,SRC_TYPE_CD
FROM DB.CPT
QUALIFY
   COUNT(*) 
   OVER (PARTITION BY NAME,DESC,SRC_TYPE_CD 
         ORDER BY CODE
         ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) > 1
         ) WITH DATA 
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Creating a table like the original one for test purpose:

```
CREATE  TABLE DP_DB.CE_TEST AS 
(SELECT * FROM DB.EVNT WHERE 
SRC_TYPE_CD='CRM' and CODE is not null)
WITH DATA AND STATS
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Updating the CE_TEST with the volatile table:

```
update a from DP_DB.CE_TEST a, vt b
set CODE= b.CORRECT_CODE where 
a.CODE in ( select b.INCORRECT_CODE from VT)
```

The above update is failing with the product join violation. I don't have any other matching column  in the two table. What else can i do to optimize this query?

Below is the sample from VT:

```
Name               Desc CORRECT_CODE    INCORRECT_CODE  SRC_TYPE_CD
700 Calls Service   100 592              601    CRM
700 Calls Service   100 592              595    CRM
700 Calls Service   100 592              597    CRM
700 Calls Service   100 592              598    CRM
700 Calls Service   100 592              594    CRM
```

Thanks,

Amit

Comment: Can't you simply use `update a from DP_DB.CE_TEST a, vt b
set CODE= b.CORRECT_CODE where 
a.CODE = b.INCORRECT_CODE and a. NAME = b.NAME and a. DESC = b. DESC and a.SRC_TYPE_CD = b.SRC_TYPE_CD` This seems to match the way you partition in the CREATE TABLE. Of course this assumes that the combination of those 4 columns is unique.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth,
I can't use this condtion:
and a. NAME = b.NAME and a. DESC = b. DESC and a.SRC_TYPE_CD = b.SRC_TYPE_CD as name and desc are not present in the other table.
Using the = condtion was not giving the correct result for a sample i have tested.
Any other option? I thought of trying merge.

Comment: If your code wasn't failing due to TASM it would fail with an error similar like "target row updated by multiple source rows". Every row in your target table must mazch exactly one row in source. Don't know how get that in your case.

Comment: I didn't get target row updated by multiple source rows error. It mainly failed because of Product join. I could use Data_source_type_cd condition, the code executed for around half n hr and failed beacuse of TASm error Cpu time exceeded.

Comment: There must be a unique column combination in `vt`: `(INCORRECT_CODE)` or `(INCORRECT_CODE, SRC_TYPE_CD)`? Then use those to match: `update a from DP_DB.CE_TEST a, vt b set CODE= b.CORRECT_CODE where a.CODE = b.INCORRECT_CODE [and a.SRC_TYPE_CD = b.SRC_TYPE_CD]`. MERGE mighth be more efficient, but it's restrictd to a conditon which fully matches the PI of the target table.

Comment: Thanks Dnoeth,
Yes that combination is unique. I couldn't use merge because the PIs were not matching

Answer (score 0):

You may still get an error with target row updated by multiple source rows (you need to get rid of duplicate correct/incorrect combinations in the VT because you aren't qualifying on the other columns like name, desc, etc later))

```
update a from DP_DB.CE_TEST a, vt b
set CODE= b.CORRECT_CODE where 
a.CODE in ( select b.INCORRECT_CODE from VT)
```

should probably be

```
update a from DP_DB.CE_TEST a, vt b
set CODE= b.CORRECT_CODE
where a.CODE = b.INCORRECT_CODE
```

Comment: Hi Lombardo,
I don't see any duplicate correct/incorrect combinations in the VT. Below is a sample

Comment: Do you still see any issue with this?